# how to make a listview of objects in android and access the object fields by clicking listitems?

Tags: java, android

I have a `listview` of objects in my android application I have made it by using my custom `ArrayAdapter` and I want to get the fields of any object that now is a `listItem` by clicking the `listItem` but I haven't any idea to do this

my `Content` class is:

```
public class Content {
    public String title;
    public String text;
    public int id;
    public Date date;
}
```

and my `ContentAdapter` class:

```
public class ContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Content> {

    private ArrayList<Content> objects;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Content> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_list_item, null);
        }

        Content i = objects.get(position);

        if (i != null) {

            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            TextView ttd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptextdata);
            TextView mt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.middletext);
            TextView mtd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.middletextdata);

            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText("title");
            }
            if (ttd != null) {
                ttd.setText(i.title);
            }
            if (mt != null) {
                mt.setText("text:");
            }
            if (mtd != null) {
                mtd.setText(i.text);
            }
        }

        return v;

    }

}
```

now I want to get date and id by clicking a list item but not show them in the list view

should I add id and date fields to my custom `arrayAdapter` class to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your custom adapter holds a list of Content object, you will have to add an OnItemClickListener to your list view as below and obtain the object clicked and retrieve the attributes.

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    Content  content = (Content ) adapterView
                            .getItemAtPosition(position);
                    //from the content object retrieve the attributes you require.
                }

            });
```